# Apache webserver: How to redirect all requests to domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: apache-2.2

Something like this works for the index page:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So a url like this:

```
http://example.com gets forwarded to 
http://www.example.com
```

but this doesn't work:

```
http://example.com/robots.txt
```

I have also tried the following in .htaccess with the same results:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Please help me resolve this.

Full configuration:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://www.example.com

ProxyPass / balancer://example/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://example/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy balancer://example>
BalancerMember http://host1.example.com:8080/ route=tomcat1
BalancerMember http://host2.example.com:8080/ route=tomcat2
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

robots.txt is located on each of the tomcat servers.

Answer (score 8):

I always use a negated pattern, so *anything* that matches the Virtual Host, but doesn't match the canonical address, will be redirected.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [redirect=permanent,nocase,last]
```

This has the benefit of an unlimited and unspecified number of `ServerAlias` directives (eg, *.example.net, *.example.org, *.example.asia etc) to all redirect correctly to www.example.com)

Comment: For some reason apache looks for this file in /etc/apache2/htdocs and throws a 'File does not exist error' in the error log.

Comment: What file? I put this inside the VirtualHost block, and don't forget `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: In my case the problem is not with the root domain redirect. The problem occurs only for sub urls.

Comment: That's what the `(.*)` and the `$1` deals with. It's called a back-reference and will redirect to the same path as the original request. eg, `example.com/about-us` will be redirected to `www.example.com/about-us`

Answer (score 6):

I personally have always found a simple 301 redirect to be more than adequate for this purpose:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  oakalleyit.com
    Redirect    301 /   http://www.oakalleyit.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

It's simple, easy to read/remember, and get's the job done right.

This is actually copied from my production web server, so I know it works.

There are docs on Apache redirects available here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

And I just tested, and typing http://oakalleyit.com/user redirects correctly to http://www.oakalleyit.com/user

Answer (score 2):

This has always worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I think your missing the $ on the condition perhaps?

More info can be found here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Just noticed the link points to a non maintained version of Apache, sorry. This may also help, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: You can always edit your answer.

Comment: I felt the information was still relevant as, the information contained on the page still seems to be valid to me. It is also shows how I do my redirection at the moment as per my answer. Did think about removing it but couldn't make up my mind :-)

Comment: Thanks for replying but this didn't work. My underlying configuration is a bit more complicated than this ( I updated it above ). I use apache mod_proxy_balancer to forward requests to two tomcat servers.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache documentation page [Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) says:

***Canonical Hostnames***

*Description: The goal of this rule is to force the use of a particular hostname, in preference to other hostnames which may be used to reach the same site. For example, if you wish to force the use of **www.example.com** instead of **example.com,** you might use a variant of the following recipe.*

***Solution:***

*The very best way to solve this doesn't involve mod_rewrite at all, but rather uses the `Redirect` directive placed in a virtual host for the non-canonical hostname(s).*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName undesired.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com notthis.example.com
  Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

*You can alternatively accomplish this using the `<If>` directive:*

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
  Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</If>
```